# Can I legally display my foreign license if pulled over in the USA if I already have USA license?

Tags: legal, driving-licenses, officials

Am I required by law to have my USA license on me if I drive in the USA, or can I also have my foreign license? If pulled over, must I tell the police that I have a valid USA license or can I just display my foreign license?
Foreign licenses can't accumulate traffic points, that's why i want to show my foreign license. I am a US citizen, and I used to live in NY, and still have a NY state license, but I live most of the year out of the country, and visit the USA from time to time. So do I legally have to show my NY license or can I show my valid foreign license so i don't get points?

Comment: Are you trying to pull the "Oh gosh, I am a dumb tourist and I cannot cope with those strange mph instead of the kph?" card to get the sympathy bonus ?

Comment: Suspect it may vary from state to state...

Comment: Do you have both a foreign and your USA license, or is having the one a consequence of having the other? Are you allowed to drive in the USA with your foreign license only? What state are we talking about? Voting to close as unclear until specified.

Comment: @ThortsenS foreign licenses can't accumulate traffic points and are easy to restore if confiscated.

Comment: In case it gets answered, same question on quora (albeit for NY State, specifically): https://www.quora.com/unanswered/Is-it-legal-to-show-foreign-drivers-license-in-NY-in-case-someone-gets-pulled-over

Comment: Please indicate what state you're in. I agree with @MarkMayo and mts; that affects the answer. In Pennsylvania, e.g., you can drive with a valid foreign driver’s license for up to a year, which dates from the most recent entry, restarting each time you enter the country (and you should have an International Driving Permit too). If the state has no reciprocity with the country, and no IDP, you have a problem.

Comment: @MarkMayo that quora question is somewhat self answering, since it notes that to drive with a foreign license you must be a nonresident, and then asks about someone with a NY State license, who is necessarily a resident. The same will probably be true in every state; the interesting question is whether you can show a non-US license when you reside in and hold a license from a US state different from the one where you are pulled over.

Comment: Foreign licenses can't accumulate traffic points, that's why i want to show my foreign license. I am a US citizen, and I used to live in NY, and still have a NY state license, but I live most of the year out of the country, and visit the USA from time to time. So do I legally have to show my NY license or can I show my valid foreign license so i don't get points?

Comment: @smn is your foreign license from your place of residence?  If so, then I doubt you will get in trouble for showing it.

Comment: In general, foreign licences do work for a 30 days since entry the state, after that you could get in troubles.

Comment: Whether or not it is legal, I doubt this would be effective.  When you show your foreign license, I'd think they would probably look up your name in their database, see that you have a NY license, and assign the points there.

Comment: I suspect it will not work because you also have to should your registration. That will show you own a car in the US, unless you *borrowed* the car somehow. If it's a rental, might work if you also showed your foreign license to the rental company.

Comment: @Itai given that the person lives outside the US, it's likely that the car is in fact either a borrowed or a rental.

Comment: @NateEldredge my former boss, an American, used to show his Belgian license in the US all the time.  He also had a US license, though I don't remember what state.  I don't think he ever got into trouble for it, he just said "I live in Belgium."  However, new databases and systems can be developed at any time, of course, so past performance is no guarantee of future results.

Comment: Would your NY License have expired? If so, then it's not valid, then you would have to show the other one. I think, Better call legal advice if you want to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

In [New York State](https://dmv.ny.gov/driver-license/drive-new-york-state), you can legally drive using your foreign drivers license and the state does not require that you carry an International Driving Permit. That you retain your NY license becomes coincidental, as you would no longer be considered a resident. That may become an issue when renewing, but that's off topic.

Should you be stopped, and present your foreign license, the police will run your name in their in-vehicle computer. The first search will be in the [DMV](https://dmv.ny.gov/dmv-records/looking-dmv-records) database, which has information on where you 'live,' your driving record, and, in some states, your biometrics, including a photo. Other databases that may accessed during a traffic stop reveal any outstanding arrest warrants and criminal history, either in local police records or the Federal [National Crime Information Center](https://www.fbi.gov/services/cjis/ncic).

So the answer is, yes, you can show only your non-US driving license.  Doing so might avoid repercussions on the sole occasion. However, a record will be created of the offense against the license you present. If the officer does not connect you to your DMV-issued license, you got lucky. If/when the connection to your State-issued license is made... well then, you know the rest.

Comment: Do you have any source for your description of the database searches?

Comment: @phoog that the police access the state DMV or that they can look in other dbases? I added the links, had asked my precinct what it can access; I changed it to be conditional. It varies by location, but traffic stops can, and do, run checks.

Comment: I know they can and do run checks, but you make specific assertions about what checks they will run, and the consequences of those checks, that appear to be speculative.